# How to choose a yeshiva for an adult?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, torah-study, adult-learning, yeshiva-school

Usually a parent would have the job of deciding during their youth where to go and as a result will have a better idea of where he wants to go for adult learning. What do the sources have to say about how to go about finding and choosing the right yeshiva for someone who didn't have the benefit of growing up with a Jewish education?

Comment: I don't think it's true that someone who was brought up with a Jewish education, when it comes time for him to go to _y'shiva_ as an adult (postsecondary _y'shiva_, a/k/a _y'shiva g'dola_), his parent has the job of deciding. Naturally, his parents should advise him to the best of their ability (and his receptiveness), but it's his decision (modulo any financial or other constraints).

Comment: two suggestions. 1. a yeshiva which is committed to following halacha. a yeshiva which does not follow halacha is pasul. 2. a yeshiva with people like you studying there. important not to try to jump the ladder.

Comment: @msh210 edited to make my point more clear. thanks

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120794/prerequisites-for-attending-yeshiva-as-a-middle-aged-baal-teshuva/120867#120867

Answer (score 3):

The main sentence is that "אין אדם למד, אלא ממקום שלבו חפץ" (A person can not study Torah, unless from a place that his heart wants) [Avoda Zara 19 page 1).

So as long as it is a yeshiva that coinsides with the Halacha it is good! Also if you tried it a out a little bit and liked it than better!

Of course there are pros with every type of Yeshiva that are pretty objective. If you ask about Israeli "Dati Leumi" Yeshivas I can give you some main ideas of each one (in the comments).